# Regex to replace one string with another in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Instead of wondering what regex I need for each time I need a regex, I like to learn how to do basic string replacement with regexes.

How do you take one string and replace it with another with regexes in PHP ?

For example how do you take all '/' and replace them with '%' ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: There's good documentation on the **[PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)** with many examples too (at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Be sure not to ignore `strtr` and `str_replace` where applicable. Regular expressions are great but not always necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to do basic string replacement (i.e. replace all 'abc' with '123') then you can use **[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)**, which doesn't require using regex. For basic replacements, this will be easier to set up and should run faster.

If you want to use this as a tool to learn regex though (or need more complicated replacements) then **[`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)** is the function you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).  For your question

```
 $string = "some/with/lots/of/slashes";
 $new_string = preg_replace("/\//","%",$string);
 echo $new_string;
```

Comment: If you use something else than `/` as the delimiter, you don't have to escape it inside the expression.

Answer (score 0):

> I like to learn how to do basic string replacement with regexes.

That's a little broad for this forum. However, to answer a more specific question like:

> For example how do you take all '/' and replace them with '%' ?

You could do that like this:

```
$result = preg_replace('#\/#', '%', 'Here/is/a/test/string.');
```

Here is a [Rubular that proves the regex](http://rubular.com/r/LrLLwy0gnQ).

Comment: The Rubular you posted adds the delimiters for you.

Comment: My point was that you were missing the forward slashes to delimit your regular expression.  The Rubular link you posted addes the forward slashes for you, but preg_replace will now.  I see that you're now using #, but I'm not sure that would work in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Note, you are not limited to using the common `/` delimiter, which means when working with forward slashes it is often easier to change to a different delimiter EG.

```
$mystring = 'this/is/random';
$result = preg_replace('#/#', '%', $mystring);
```

This will make '#' the delimiter, rather than the standard '/', so it means you do not need to escape the slash.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this simply with [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) which is very suitable for character mapping, e.g.

```
strtr('My string has / slashes /', '/', '%');
```

If you want to also replace the letter `a` with a dash:

```
strtr('My string has / slashes /', '/a', '%-');
```

As you can see, the second and third argument define the transformation map.